# What type represents a type in typescript?

Tags: typescript

so given

```
class Foo {
}

interface TypeProvider() {
    type(): ? ;
}

class Bar implements TypeProvider {
    type(): ? {
        return (Foo);
    }
}

class Baz implements TypeProvider {
    type(): ? {
        return (Bar);
    }
}
```

`Foo` is a class but if I'm returning a class  from a method, what type do I assign the method signature?

as an aside is `return (Foo)` and `return Foo` the same thing? if they're different I'm not certain I don't want the latter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be the `Foo` constructor:

```
class Bar {
    type(): { new(): Foo } {
        return (Foo);
    }
}
```

Or:

```
interface FooConstructor {
    new(): Foo;
}

class Bar {
    type(): FooConstructor {
        return (Foo);
    }
}
```

Comment: maybe as an also... is `return Foo` different from `return (Foo)`? (hoping I didn't accidentally write the wrong question)

Comment: From the question title, isn't the OP asking about a type that represents any constructor?

Comment: There's no need to have brackets around it, you can just `return Foo`. @JuanMendes I thought he meant this specific type and just wrote `type` so that it would be more understandable when reading the title. In any case a type that represents any constructor will be: `{ new(): any }`.

Comment: ah I updated the question though this should still be correct.